# Java threading: pass values into the thread (probably race condition)

Tags: java, multithreading

Race condition are quite tricky, as I had to [learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160211/java-synchronization-of-variables-between-threads).

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean active;
    private volatile Job job;

    public MyThread() {
        active = true;
        job = null;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (isActive()) {
            if( job != null) {
                doIt();
            }
        }
    }

    public void finish() {
        this.active = false;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    private void doIt() {
        int c = job.a + job.b;
        job.result(c);
        job = null;
    }

    public call processJob( Job j ) {
        this.job = j;
    }
}
```

This works correctly if I use a low amount of threads, but runs into issues when a large amount of them is running simultaneously. By issues I mean that `job.result(c);` is not called for some threads, although none of them have been stopped.

I assume that this happens because I fail to correctly add jobs if called from a different process via `processJob(j)`. **Question**: how should I do that correctly?

Comment: How do you plan on setting (or modifying) job and active?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like you have a [consumer / producer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) design.

I suggest you use a thread safe collection such as [`BlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) (or something similar) to pass the data from one thread to the other.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what aioobe says, I would suggest stop using Thread class to do the work and use the concurrency package in java instead. You can create a `Callable` class and cancel it using `Future` that is returned from the `ExecutorService`.